# OpenStack + Juju: tenant_network_types in ml2_conf.ini

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

how do I configure tenant_network_types in juju (neutron)? The config states it will be overwritten (which it realy does) but there is no parameter in the settings.

Thanks.

Comment: I still did not find a working solution for this. I updated my juju charms but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file in question is managed by the charm, and if it is manually modified, you run the risk of losing your custom setting when hooks, relations and other events occur.

In order to manage that configuration data with Juju, the charm would need to grow a new charm config option.  Please feel free to raise a bug against https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/neutron-gateway.  Be sure to include a description of your specific use case, and a request to consider adding this feature.